# soql knowledge inner query error

Tags: apex, soql, knowledge

When i try to write an inner query using knowledge object its fetching error.
having the Applicable_model__c is a custom object.

SELECT Id, Title,(Select Id from Applicable_model__r) FROM knowledge__kav

i am getting the below error

SELECT Id, Title,(Select Id from Applicable_model__r) FROM knowledge__kav
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:34
Didn't understand relationship 'Applicable_model__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

can some one help on this.

Comment: Usually child relationship names are plural. Did you try `Applicable_models__r`?

Comment: Yes got it, It my bad thanks for you help